# "Will" or "Would"?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, will-shall

In my understanding, while talking about future whether to use "would" or "will" depends on our perception and subjective.

If you are confident about something you can use 'will' instead of 'would' and, use 'would' if you are less confident about something( while talking about future).

For instance,

> 1. Egypt has decided to build a new city near Cairo, that city will create more jobs

( It means we are sure that city is going to be constructed and at the same moment ,it is going to create more jobs-100% confident that it will happen).

> 2. Egypt has decided to build a new city near Cairo, that city would create more jobs

( Not sure about the job creation because of unreliable government , and happens only if everything goes well- it means, only if government makes city and creates more job).

It would be great if someone could help me on above regards, I am totally going insane on this 'would' and 'will' confusion.

Comment: I think it's "over-analysis" to suppose using ***would*** rather than ***will*** in this context is a reasonable way of *indicating doubt* about whether the action will in fact take place. If Egypt ***has decided***, it's something they ***will do***, and any associated consequences ***will follow***. You'd only use ***would*** in a more overtly "hypothetical scenario" construction such as *Egypt **is considering** building a new city that **would** create more jobs*.

Comment: I also doubt that many if any native speakers would draw any such inference from a context where *either* verb form would be equally acceptable *(Egypt **wants** to build a new city that **will/would** create new jobs)*. It's really not much more than a meaningless stylistic choice there.

Comment: So in your opinion both are correct, and it all depends on our perception??

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "correct". I could, for example, say *"Last century, Fleming made a discovery [that would change the course of history](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22that+would+change+the+course+of+history%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)"* (it already has). Or *"Guy Fawkes conceived a plan that would change the course of history"* (but in fact it never will). We wouldn't ordinarily use ***will*** in either of those contexts, but it would be perfectly "correct" - *if that's what you wanted to say* (that the *current* future will be changed by the past).

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct! In the first one you said

> Egypt has decided to make new city near Cairo, that city will create more jobs

I think you meant:

> Egypt has decided to make **a** new city near Cairo, that city will create more jobs

Answer (score 1):

When I hear (or use)  "would" as a form of "to be" for future tense, I always use it *not* based on the chance of the event happening, but on a pre-condition coming true.
To use your example, for a future, unconditional,  event, I **will** simply use "will".

> Egypt has decided to build new city near Cairo. It will create more jobs.

On the other hand, **if** we were to make the new city a *condition* of new jobs, I **would** (see how it works? :) ) use your second form

> *If* Egypt decides to build a new city near Cairo, that city would create more jobs

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks heaps.
I've realised that if we use 'would' instead of 'will' for future tense that means there needs to be some conditional whether you mention it or not in your sentence. 

For example:
-That would be awesome (only if some condition fullfilled)
-That will be awesome ( no condition needed)

I mean its like using could/might for future probability. Am I right? ?

Comment: Please click on the check-mark next to my answer. Also if you agree +1 it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Prashant, There is one more small silly confusion. Is it ok to use "would' for present probability instead of 'could'. For example,  I am in Barber and he asks me for which number (for machine)..I am still confuse and say that "no 1 should be alright"(not sure)..can I say "no 1 would be alright (not sure)" or "no 1 could be alright (not sure)"..

Comment: @PradhanKiran would give a direct answer to a direct question. e.g. "Please go with number 1, Thank you."  There no probability. Does that make sense? Also, if this answer worked for you, please click the tick mark next to my answer if you don't mind, that helps others looking for similar issues.

Comment: Cool!! But it was just small confusion that whether 'would' is used for present probability, instead of 'could' or 'might'. I mean in other sense we are not sure about something, for example one girl come to me and ask for good wine and just says 'do you think that would be nice ??'. (Actually I had this real situation and girl was asking me for good wine )